# google cloud messaging gives null

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I download a google cloud messaging from this site. 
[Site](http://learnsauce.com/)

Only if i run the app in Genymotion the notification comes up. But not the text. 
the notification gives a Null.

I have 2 java's GcmBroadcastReceiver And GcmIntentService. 
but I do not know where to look for the error.

GcmIntentService:

```
package com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
String TAG="pavan";

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    Log.d("pavan","in gcm intent message "+messageType);
    Log.d("pavan","in gcm intent message bundle "+extras);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
GCM
         * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
         * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
         * recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

            String recieved_message=intent.getStringExtra("text_message");
            sendNotification("message recieved :" +recieved_message);

            Intent sendIntent =new Intent("message_recieved");
            sendIntent.putExtra("message",recieved_message);
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(sendIntent);
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark)
                    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                     .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

GcmIntentService

```
package com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;


public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

The output on Genymotion:

[image: Genymotion screen]

Log:

```
10-17 12:29:25.998 12541-17229/com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication D/pavan: in gcm intent message gcm
10-17 12:29:25.998 12541-17229/com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication D/pavan: in gcm intent message bundle Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=268]
10-17 12:29:26.006 12541-17229/com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication I/pavan1: data =Bundle[{android.support.content.wakelockid=9, price=A test , collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=693176399203}]
10-17 12:29:26.010 12541-12541/com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication D/pavan: in local braod null
```

price=A test

that's what I send.

Comment: Could you show the format of the downstream message being sent from the server? Also have a look at the link here it shows the recommended way to do GCM on android. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line you need to look at:

```
String recieved_message=intent.getStringExtra("text_message");
sendNotification("message recieved :" +recieved_message);
```

`recieved_message` is null, for some reasons. Log the data

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "intent.getExtras() >> " + intent.getExtras().toString());
```

the data should be your `JSON` playload, and you need to parse that correctly.

update your post with that log maybe I can help you further

---

Try this:

```
String receivedMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("text_message");
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received message >> " + receivedMessage);
```

Comment: also does not work. Gives Received message >> null In the logdata.

Comment: @user3819560 what about `intent.getExtras() >>`

Comment: Gives this. 
10-17 12:50:56.790 1575-1759/com.example.provenlogic1.myapplication D/pava22: intent.getExtras() >> Bundle[{android.support.content.wakelockid=1, from=693176399203, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, price=A test}]

Comment: Look at it u called it price not received_message

Comment: `String receivedMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("price");`

Comment: For some reason it does not work it all!
Now I have nothing left

Answer (score 0):

I had that in my project , The problem in serverSide codes , if its php , change your codes with this

```
array( "message" => $message )

$greetMsg = $_POST['message'];

$message =  $respJson;
```

```html
<?php
 //Generic php function to send GCM push notification
   function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registation_ids,$message) {
  //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
        $url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registation_ids,
            'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
        );
  // Update your Google Cloud Messaging API Key
  if (!defined('GOOGLE_API_KEY')) {
   define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "");   
  }
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);    
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
?>
<?php
 include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
  $selUsers = $_POST['sendmsg'];
  if(empty($selUsers))
  {
    echo("You didn't select any users.");
  }
  else
  {
 $resp = "<tr id='header'><td>GCM Response [".date("h:i:sa")."]</td></tr>";
    $userCount = count($selUsers);
 $greetMsg = $_POST['message'];
 $respJson = $greetMsg;
 $registation_ids = array();
 for($i=0; $i < $userCount; $i++)
    {
     $gcmRegId = $db->getGCMRegID($selUsers[$i]);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($gcmRegId);
  //Add RegIds retrieved from DB to $registration_ids
  array_push($registation_ids, $row['gcm_regid']);
    }
 // JSON Msg to be transmitted to selected Users
 $message =  $respJson;
 $pushsts = sendPushNotificationToGCM($registation_ids, $message);
 $resp = $resp."<tr><td>".$pushsts."</td></tr>";
 echo "<table>".$resp."</table>";
  }

?>
```